Beta-function tricky problem

A video game company is developing a new game in the line. To ensure proper balance between players, an algorithm is used that randomly assigns a level of
Skill for each new player. The algorithm generates two independent scores with values ​​between
$0$ and $1$: $T$ (playtime) and $P$ (precision). A player's skill level is defined as
the ratio between your accuracy score and the sum of your accuracy score and your score
of playing time. Players with a skill level below $60\%$ are sent to
the practice area, while those with an equal or higher level can play online.
Find the probability that a randomly chosen player goes to the practice area.
Hint: Let $U_1, U_2$ be random variables such that $U_i \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0, 1)$ then $\dfrac{U_1}{U_1+U_2}\sim \operatorname{Beta}(1, 1)$.

I was trying to define players' ability first as:
$$X = \frac{P}{T+P}$$
then using hint:
$$X = \frac{U_1}{U_1+U_2}$$
as this equation follows the beta probability distribution
$$P(X<0.6) = 0.6$$
is this correct?

Not sure the rules are clear.  The assignments are random?  What's the point of that?  How does that ensure "proper balance" ?  And what exactly is assigned randomly?  Are $T,P$ assigned randomly?  Is that what $U_1, U_2$ are meant to denote?

If my guesses are correct (far from clear), then $\frac {U_1}{U_1+U_2}≤.6$ is the same as $U_1≤\frac 32 \times U_2$, and the probability is easily worked out by drawing a picture.

Simulations show this to be about 66%, but I want to work this out because something feels odd in the setup. Can you share where this came from - a textbook, perhaps (with the name and author)?

@SeanRoberson my teacher gave it to me I do not know the book, what are your concerns?

@lulu can you elaborate more?

The joint distribution is the unit square. Draw the line which defines the region I described.  The complement is a right triangle.   No need for complicated computations

But, as I said initially,  the problem set up is oddly phrased.  I made a string of assumptions that make sense as a math problem,  but they don't really make sense in the context you describe.

@lulu ask me a question so I can ask to my teacher

I don't understand the set up. Why have a complicated, random,  filter? If you want to hold $60%$ of players back,  just do that uniformly at random.  Something is missing.

@lulu it is a problem to practice the Betta function

As I say,  it has nothing to do with the beta distribution. If my interpretation is correct,  it's a simple geometric problem based on a uniform distribution.

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
The problem is hard to follow.  Specifically, the purported background (constructing some filter for access to a game) doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.  Ignoring all of that, one might interpret the problem as asking the following:  Suppose you have two independent random variables $U_1,U_2$ both of which are just uniform on the interval $(0,1)$.  What is the probability that $\frac {U_1}{U_1+U_2}<.6$?   That question makes sense (though it may not be the intended one).  In any case, we can answer that one.
We note that $$\frac {U_1}{U_1+U_2}<.6\iff U_1<.6\times(U_1+U_2)\iff U_1<\frac 32\times U_2$$
Now, the joint distribution of the two variables may be modeled by the uniform distribution on the unit square.  The good region is the region above the line $U_1=\frac 32\times U_2$ ("above" here treats $U_2$ as the vertical axis, and $U_1$ as the horizontal).  The complement of that region is the right triangle with legs $1$ and $\frac 23$ and that triangle has area $\frac 13$.  Thus the desired probability is $1-\frac 13=\frac 23$.
I note that this fits the simulations mentioned by @SeanRobertson in the comments but all that is likely to mean is that the two of us have interpreted the problem the same way.

the context of this problem is the beta function so the problem must be done with the beta function

$\frac{U_1}{U_1+U_2}$ follwos beta(1,1) distribution which is the unit square

$\beta(1,1)$ is the uniform distribution on the unit interval.  See, e.g, this. $\frac {U_1}{U_1+U_2}$ is not uniform on the unit interval.
Again, I don't see any connection to the $\beta$ distribution here.

To stress:  I am not at all sure I have interpreted the question correctly.  As I have mentioned, it is quite hard to follow.  I thought it was worth being explicit about my interpretation and the method for solving that.  Of course, different interpretations might play out differently.

can you explain step 3 I am lost there $U<1.5 \times U_2$

$U_1<.6\times (U_1+U_2)\iff U_1<.6U_1+.6U_2\iff .4U_1<.6U_2\iff 4U_1<6U_2\iff U_1<\frac 64\times U_2\iff U_1<\frac 32\times U_2$.
